# WM_MBUTTONDOWN doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse

I use WM_MBUTTONDOWN to keep track of middle mouse button when it's pressed. So, when I click the middle mouse button at the mouse wheel, it will display the message on the console. I wonder why it doesn't work. Is WM_MBUTTONDOWN for another usage?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK UI::WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        //  The message is post when we destroy the window.
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
        cout << "Middle button clicked" << endl;
        break;


         // Default handling for other messages.
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[image: output]

Mouse used: Logitech

Comment: Um, `cout` doesn't work in GUI apps.

Comment: I use int main() instead of int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) to pop up console window. So it's not the issue.

Comment: A smaller picture of the mouse would have been better. On a serious note, your code doesn't really relate with your output. Where are you logging left and right click information to console?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a driver issue. On some mice `WM_MBUTTONDOWN` message is not received. Make sure you use a mouse driver that supports middle button.

Check if the middle button works in other applications - if not, it is a driver issue.

Comment: Logitech, specifically, offers tools to allow end users to control what the middle button does – or whether it is even enabled. You should check to make sure that it's set correctly.